# How to put React component inside HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I have: an **array of HTML strings**, eg `["<h1>Hi", "</h1>"`].
I want to place `<MyReactComponent/>` in between them
(thus achieving a layout that would be in jsx:
`<h1>Hi<MyReactComponent/></h1>`).

How do I achieve this?

---

I've tried:

- `Babel.transform('<h1>Hi<MyReactComponent/></h1>')` (using standalone Babel). It does work, but requires me to stringify `<MyReactComponent/>`, **which is not elegant and probably will break some day**.
- to use regular jsx `render() => <MyReactComponent/>`, and then, on `componentDidMount` prepending HTML by manipulating DOM, **but browser inserts closing tags automatically**, so I'll be getting `<h1>Hi</h1><MyReactComponent/><h1></h1>`
- to use `jsx-to-html` library and `innerHTML`, to convert `<MyReactComponent/>` to HTML string, combine it with `<h1>Hi</h1>`, but it destroy any React interaction with `<MyReactComponent/>`.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the strings with `React.createElement` to create the DOM? Is this an option or are you looking for generating `jsx` only ?

Comment: it absolutely is an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [html-to-react](https://github.com/mikenikles/html-to-react).

This library converts the string to a node tree of DOM elements, then transforms each node to a React element using a set of instructions that you define. I believe that it depends on the string being valid markup though, so you might have to change `"<h1>Hi<MyReactComponent/></h1"` to something like `"<h1>Hi<x-my-react-component></x-my-react-component></h1>`.

Example:

```
import { Parser, ProcessNodeDefinitions } from "html-to-react";
import MyReactComponent from "./MyReactComponent";

const customElements = {
    "x-my-react-component": MyReactComponent
};

// Boilerplate stuff
const htmlParser = new Parser(React);
const processNodeDefinitions = new ProcessNodeDefinitions(React);
function isValidNode(){
    return true;
}

// Custom instructions for processing nodes
const processingInstructions = [
    // Create instruction for custom elements
    {
        shouldProcessNode: (node) => {
            // Process the node if it matches a custom element
            return (node.name && customElements[node.name]);
        },
        processNode: (node) => {
            let CustomElement = customElements[node.name];
            return <CustomElement/>;
        }
    },
    // Default processing
    {
        shouldProcessNode: () => true,
        processNode: processNodeDefinitions.processDefaultNode
    }
];

export default class MyParentComponent extends Component {
    render () {
        let htmlString = "<h1>Hi<x-my-react-component></x-my-react-component></h1>";
        return htmlParser.parseWithInstructions(htmlString, isValidNode, processingInstructions);
    }
}
```

The essential part here is `processingInstructions`. Every node in the DOM tree is checked against each instruction in the array, starting from the top, until `shouldProcessNode` returns true, and the node is transformed to a React element by the corresponding `processNode` function. This allows for rather complex processing rules, but it quickly gets a bit messy if you want to process nested custom elements. The result of the example is the equivalent of

```
<h1>
    Hi
    <MyReactComponent/>
</h1>
```

in JSX syntax. Hope this helps!

Comment: (and here is my final implementation if someone is interested https://github.com/lakesare/memcode/blob/c049ae23ecabbd502116c440ff8b2d39fd14be88/frontend/services/problemContentToJsx.js)